equicontinuity vs uniform equicontinuity
Recall that if  $(X,\rho),(Y,d)$  are metric spaces and  $\mathcal{F}$   is a collection of functions from $X$ to $Y$,  then  $\mathcal{F}$ is called 
a)  "equicontinuous at $x_0$"  (where $x_0\in X$)  if for every $\varepsilon>0$
there exists a $\delta>0$ such that for every $f\in \mathcal{F}$ and every $x\in X$ with
$\rho(x,x_0)<\delta$ it holds $d(f(x),f(x_0))<\varepsilon$.
b)  "equicontinuous" , if it is equicontinuous at $x_0$ for every $x_0\in X$
c) "uniformly equicontinuous", if for every $\varepsilon>0$ there exists $\delta>0$
such that  for every $f\in \mathcal{F}$ and every $x,y\in X$ with
$\rho(x,y)<\delta$ it holds $d(f(x),f(y))<\varepsilon$.
The obvious example of a family that is equicontinuous but not uniformly equicontinuous
is the singleton $\mathcal{F}=\{f\}$ where $f$ is a function that is continouous but not uniformly continuous.
An obvious observation is that if  $\mathcal{F}$   is uniformly equicontinuous then every
$f\in  \mathcal{F}$   uniformly continuous.
Also  it is known that if $X$ is compact and $\mathcal{F}$ is equicontinuous then  $\mathcal{F}$ is uniformly equicontinuous.
I am seeking for an example of a pair of metric spaces $X,Y$ and a family of functions $\mathcal{F}$  such that 
a) $\mathcal{F}$ is equicontinuous
b)  $\mathcal{F}$ is not uniformly  equicontinuous
c) each $f\in\mathcal{F}$  is uniformly continuous.

@ Michael Burr.  Of course I was trying to find an example  either when $X=\mathbb{R}$ or when  $X$ is  an open interval of $\mathbb{R}$ (i.e. $X=(0,1)$)  Do you have a specific example?

I'm sorry, I misunderstood the question, you wanted (a), (b), and (c) simultaneously, not one at a time.  I have deleted my comment,.

Let $\omega:\mathbb R \rightarrow \mathbb R$ denote any nontrivial continuous function with support in $[-1,1]$. To be more precise let $\omega(t) = \max\{0, 1 - |t|\}$ (the foregoing estimations use this exact formula for $\omega$, but arbitrary $\omega$ gives rise to a counterexample).
Now let $f_n(t) = n \omega(t - 2n)$ with integer $n$. Thus, $f_n(t)$ has support in $[2n-1, 2n+1]$ and, therefore, each point $t \in \mathbb R$ belongs to at most two sets of the form $\mathrm{supp} f_n$. From this it is clear that $\mathcal F = \{f_n: n \in \mathbb Z\}$ is equicontinuous. Each function $f_n$ has compact support and, therefore, it is uniformly continuous due to Cantor's theorem.
Finally, we prove that $\mathcal F$ is not uniformly equicontinuous. Indeed, fix $\varepsilon > 0$ (it is sufficient to find only one $\varepsilon$ for which the definition of uniform equicontinuity fails, but here it fails for all $\varepsilon > 0$) and consider arbitrary $\delta > 0$. Find $n \in \mathbb Z$ such that $n\min\{\delta/2,1\}  > \varepsilon$ and consider $x = 2n-1$ and $y = 2n-1 + \min\{\delta/2, 1\}$. Then $|f_n(y) - f_n(x)| = n \min\{\delta/2, 1\} > \varepsilon$ with $|y - x| < \delta$.

Very well explained. To be sincere it didn't pass my mind to take functions with (almost) pairwise disjoint support. This is the crucial idea!
